# Adobe Adam and Eve, C++: How to create a clickable button, trackbar, text input field and an image?

Tags: c++, user-interface, boost, adobe, asl

So I found out that I need a gui for my [app](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/). I have a crossplatform video broadcaster. (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X). I use a lot of boost and thought give ASL a shot. But I found out there are no tutorials on how to do what I need.

So I ask you to help me with one - how to create a new window with clickable button (on click some function would be called), trackbar (on drag some function would be called), text input field and an image?

***Update:***

[How to build this thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397501/how-to-compile-asl-boost-based-adobe-c-gui-library-on-windows-7)

Found some great amount of samples here [asl_1.0.43_begin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adobe-source/files/adobe-source/1.0.43/apl_1.0.43.zip/download)

Comment: Looked at that as an option once upon a time and found it to be overly complex without a lot of documentation or community support. I went with QT as a cross platform GUI framework.

Comment: All platforms release in ASL (with docs) is 11mbs... And QT is like 300 per platform + it has duplications of nearly all stuff I use from boost...

Comment: Boost is pretty large too and .NET is massive. My philosophy is hard drives are cheap, developers aren't.

Comment: I agree with AJG85, I combine Qt with boost without any issues, Qt has a well-defined and easy to use API, a large user base, a pretty liberal lincense and it looks good + you only link to what you need: so e.g. to QtCore and QtGui. You don't need to link to QNetwork, etc if you use the boost functionality. The only thing you need to mix carefully is the boost signals lib and the Qt signals though that issue has been documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASL delivers some examples by itslef (in LIB_ROOT/test directory).There are open source application "mission photo" which uses asl too, but I don't know how good its sourcecode is. Anyway, here is the link http://www.missioncode.org/#Welcome. Good look !