# how to compile ASL (boost based Adobe C++ gui library) on windows 7?

Tags: c++, boost, adobe, compilation, asl

So I am triing to compile [ASL](http://stlab.adobe.com/) on windows 7.

- I got [Adobe C++ Library files, docs and examples from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adobe-source/files/adobe-source/) to `%ASL%`
- I have downloaded and compiled boost (in some other folder `%boost%`)
- So now I have compiled Boost (all libs), bjam, VS 2008 installed (I have it in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`)
- Now I try to run `%ASL%/tools/build.bat` but I get some strange lines like

  > Found compiler at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\
  >
  > Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
  >   Sintax error in filename
  >   Can not find C:\Users\Avesta\Downloads\asl_1.0.43 (1)\source_release\tools*.obj

What shall I do? How to compile ASL on windows 7?

***Update:***
So I tried [@vnm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397501/how-to-compile-asl-boost-based-adobe-c-gui-library-on-windows-7/6418957#6418957) (created a new folder and done each step provided by him one at a time) I forgot to unpack TBB... after unpacking TBB all compiled correctly=)

But one question stands for me - how to make results of build more clean (I mean thay lay into folder like %ASL%\built_artifacts\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi and there you see `libasl.lib` it is quite a long path to navigate... is it possible to get one clean folder like adobe/bin/ with stuff like `libasl.lib`, `libasl_dev.lib` and `libadobe_widgets.lib` in it? )

Comment: "failed updating some targets" means that there was error during compiling / linking or during other activities specified by bjam input file. This can be due wrong libs versions or wrong configurations etc. Please, post some of errors (maybe to some online posting service like pastebin) and I'll try to help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to build asl using .bat script shipped with library,
but direct using of bjam did the job.

- download and install boost libraries ([version 1.45](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.45.0/)), 
  [intel tbb libraries](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/file.php?fid=77) (last version), [apl and asl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adobe-source/files/adobe-source/1.0.43/) (last versions)
- [compile](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/jam.html) or download pre-compilled [bjam](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/) and put it on %PATH%
- unpack downloaded libraries to disk using next layout:

`\%PROJ_ROOT%
    \boost_libraries (put contents of archive_file/boost_1_45_0 here)
    \intel_tbb_libraries
    \platform_release (put contents of apl archive here)
    \adobe_source_libraries (put contents of asl/source_release archive here)`

- In next step we need to fix %PROJ_ROOT%\platform_release\jamroot.jam file project entry in next way:

```
  project
   : requirements
     $(DARWIN_APL_REQUIREMENTS)
     <include>. # we should add this line because compiler 
                # can't find include files during compiling tests
   : default-build
     <link>static
     <threading>multi
     <preserve-test-targets>on

   : build-dir
      $(TOP)/../built_artifacts
   ;
```

- start Visual Studio Command Prompt
- cd to %PROJ_ROOT%\adobe_source_libraries and invoke bjam
- cd to %PROJ_ROOT%\platform_release and invoke bjam

Done ! )

P.S. I have Visual C++ 2010 Express, but I think that this guide should work for VS2008 too.

Comment: have you tried to compile ASL in front of boost 1.46.1? Is it ok not have libadobe_widgets compile?

Comment: Yes. But this required additional defines (BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2) to be added to project configuration in jam file, because boost 1.46.1 uses third filesystem version.Alternativelly you can fix asl's code to work with new Boost.Filesystem. This is full jamfile for such type of build: http://pastebin.com/r5dVTLCd

Comment: Hello again!) Thank you so wary much for all your help on ASL, btw have you compiled it on any Linux flavour? and could you be our hero for a little longer and help on with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457273/adobe-eve-asl-how-to-render-eve-file-into-gui-window

Comment: And If you have any info on how to compile `libadobe_widgets` under linux please post your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461621/how-to-compile-asl-boost-based-adobe-c-gui-library-on-linux