# Is adobe ASL (adam and eve) still alive? what is a replacement?

Tags: c++, user-interface, adobe, asl

Being a fan of STL, I've been looking for a modern way of GUI development.

It seems that the latest theoretical ideas were in ASL. At least, that is what theoretical papers on gui look at. For example, [Algorithms for user interfaces](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1621630) (2009)

However, the [latest change in asl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adobe-source/files/?source=navbar) was in 2010. The [forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/adobe-source/discussion/449269/) are also seem empty. It seems that ASL is not maintained and not used a lot.

I still couldn't find anything as advanced and generic. What do people use now that fills the gap?

Comment: It depends, do you want it for only a single platform (which one?) or cross-platform?

Comment: linux and maybe play around with outputting to web(html,css,JS)

Comment: looks like linux is not well supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461621/how-to-compile-asl-boost-based-adobe-c-gui-library-on-linux so i'm mainly looking for projects that use the same ideas.

Comment: The only GUI C++ library that I know of with some some standard-library support is [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

Answer (score 4):

It's been a few years, so I'm sure the original questioner has moved on by now. However, for anybody with the same question, it appears that development [has moved to GitHub](https://github.com/stlab/adobe_source_libraries). As of January 2014, this is not stated on the old ASL website.