# Adobe Eve ASL: how to render eve file into gui window?

Tags: c++, user-interface, boost, cross-platform, adobe

So We have simple `.eve` and `.adam` files, [compiled ASL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397501/how-to-compile-asl-boost-based-adobe-c-gui-library-on-windows-7), and all includes required for `boost` and `adobe`. We need a crossplatform function to make our layout rendered, and movable as real window on our platform (we need it for Mac OS X, Windows, Linux). How to do such thing?

We have started trying to move in direction of simplifiing some tutorials we found in ASL folder (`begin`) and got some results [you can see here](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/#svn/branches/v0.4/ASL.AdameAndEve.Tutorial/src/CloudAdamAndEve). But our approach is not crossplatform or any way eazy to get=( So we ask for your halp in getting how to display a simple window with ok button defined by adam and eve files?

Here is example of simple Adam and simple eve files

```
layout my_dialog
{
    view dialog(name: localize(\"<xstr id='my_dialog_name'>My Dialog</xstr>\"))
    {
        slider(bind: @my_value, format: {first: 0, last: 100});
        edit_number(name: 'Value:', bind: @my_value, format: '#', alt: 'Alters the value of the slider');
        button (items: [
                           { name: localize(\"<xstr id='ok'>OK</xstr>\"), action: @ok, bind: @result, alt: 'Perform the command with the current settings' },
                           { name: localize(\"<xstr id='reset'>Reset</xstr>\"), action: @reset, modifiers: @opt, alt: 'Reset the dialog settings' }
                       ]);
    }
}
```

---

```
sheet my_sheet
{
interface:
   my_value: 42;
output:
   result <== { value: my_value };
}
```

that shall generate a window like this on windows:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We have done it here!)](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.4/ASL.AdameAndEve.Tutorial/src/ReturnValue.cpp) it is really simple.

Source:

```
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>
#include <adobe/future/modal_dialog_interface.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

using namespace std;

inline bool always_break(adobe::name_t, const adobe::any_regular_t&)
    { return true; }

void dialog()
{
    stringstream       sheet;
    stringstream       layout;
    boost::filesystem::path icon_directory_path;

    // The sheet for the dialog
    sheet <<
                        "sheet my_sheet\n"
                        "{\n"
                        "interface:\n"
                        "   my_value: 42;\n"
                        "output:\n"
                        "   result <== { value: my_value };\n"
                        "}\n"
    ;

    // the layout
    layout <<
                                "layout my_dialog\n"
                                "{\n"
                                "    view dialog(name: 'My Dialog')\n"
                                "    {\n"
                                "        slider(bind: @my_value, format: {first: 0, last: 100});\n"
                                "        edit_number(name: 'Value:', bind: @my_value, format: '#', alt: 'Alters the value of the slider');\n"
                                "        button (items: [\n"
                                "                           { name: 'OK', action: @ok, bind: @result, alt: 'Perform the command with the current settings' },\n"
                                "                           { name: 'Reset', action: @reset, modifiers: @opt, alt: 'Reset the dialog settings' }\n"
                                "                       ]);\n"
                                "    }\n"
                                "}\n"
        ;

    // finally set up the params for the modal dialog interface call
    adobe::dialog_result_t result(adobe::handle_dialog(adobe::dictionary_t(),
                                                       adobe::dictionary_t(),
                                                       adobe::dictionary_t(),
                                                       adobe::dialog_display_s,
                                                       layout,
                                                       sheet,
                                                       &always_break,
                                                       icon_directory_path));

    int is_checked(result.command_m[adobe::static_name_t("value")].cast<int>());
        cout << "return value: " << is_checked << endl;
}

int  main(  )
{
        dialog();
        cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```